# Does "me" indicate (1) reflexive (pronominal) or (2) dativo aspectual in the sentence "No me iba a perder el verano"

Tags: verbo-pronominal

Does *me* indicate (1) reflexive (pronominal) or (2) dativo aspectual in the sentence

> No **me** iba a perder el verano

And if it indicates either (1) or (2), can you say why it does?

Is the sentence construction similar to the one in

> **Me** leí todo el periódico

Comment: Do you mean "me"?

Comment: Yes.  I was thinking of reflexive pronouns in general.

Comment: Yes? There is not any "se" in your sentences. Please edit the title and your post replacing "se" by "me" if that is what you mean.

Comment: perderse el verano means to miss, perder alone is lose. There are two different meanings.

Comment: Me léi todo is not really necessary but could be translated here as cover to cover. Like: Me comí todo el pastel: I ate **up** the whole cake.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, *pronominal* does not exclude *dativo aspectual*. The former is about morphosyntax, the latter about semantics. *Perderse (el verano)* is a pronominal usage of the verb *perder* and it expresses a so-called “aspectual dative”. The corresponding entry at the DLE reads:

> 20. prnl. No aprovecharse algo que podía y debía ser útil, o aplicarse mal para otro fin. U. t. c. tr.

There are no simple tests to determine when a dative is an aspectual dative, but one can compare it with other, clearer examples of this. One thing you cannot do with an aspectual dative is to have a direct object that is generic or unbounded. **No me iba a perder veranos* is ungrammatical because *veranos* is unbounded (it doesn't have any specific reference or bound). *No me iba a perder un verano como este* is correct because *un verano como este* is bounded by the qualification *como este* (even if it's not definite).

Semantically, *perderse* implies a bounded, completed, finished event, just like other aspectual datives; *perderse algo* implies missing the whole thing. So this is indeed like *leerse (todo) el libro* or *tomarse una cerveza (entera)*.

Comment: A New Reference Grammar doesn't mention dativo de interés, dativo ético, dativo simpatético, or dativo aspectual although it does categorize pronominal verbs in the following categories:  reflexive, reciprocal, intransitive, se de matización, "total consumption," passive se, "special construction," and impersonal se.  So I am groping for information that will help me recognize se in all its uses <whew>, and I thank you for providing this valuable information.

Comment: Are you able to translate No me iba a perder el verano or Me leí todo el periódico to English?

Comment: I would have said "I am not going to miss the summer". In fact I would probably have re-worded it as that does not sound quite right but that would depend on the context which you did not give us. The other one is a bit impenetrable without more context.

Comment: I agree that "No me iba a perder veranos" does not sound right. However, with an adjective the indefinite plural can work: Me perdí veranos enteros yendo al campo. And with other verbs, the ungrammaticality rule does not work: Me pasé horas trabajando / Con el dinero de la herencia me compré autos y casas.

Comment: To mdewey57 and Gustavson:  Thanks.  Yes, context is essential, I think, in order to make a good translation.  (The RAE did say that the dativo aspectual had a carácter enfático.)  Almost every day (or at least several times a week) I'm made aware of the nuances found in both English and Spanish, and it would not amaze me to learn that No me iba a perder el verano or Me leí todo el periódico had meanings that could not be completely expressed in English.

Comment: @Gustavson The rule is a bit more complicated then, probably. I would argue that in *Me pasé horas trabajando* the perfective aspect of the verb could supply the definiteness that is missing in *horas* (indeed, if you said *me pasaba horas trabajando*, imperfect, that would imply repetition of a finished event rather than an event in progress). But I'd rather research this further.

Comment: After taking a walk, I have decided to submit a possible translation for "No me iba a perder el verano."  It is "I really wasn't going to miss the summer."  I think this is as close as I can translate "No me iba a perder el verano."